# Sorting three different arrays

Tags: java, sorting

This is the problem: Write a program that prompts the user to enter goods sale information including the name of the goods, quantity, and amount. First, the user is required to input the number of goods, and then input goods sale information one by one. Then the program will print out the goods information sort by quantity (from largest to smallest), and sort by amount (from largest to smallest) respectively. I'm having trouble sorting the information from the user by quantity and amount. For example, the output should be something like this:

**Sort by quantity:**

> Item     Qty  Amount
>   CD       32   459.20
>   T-Shirt  22   650.80
>   Book     14   856.89

**Sort by amount:**

> Item     Qty  Amount
>   Book     14   856.89
>   T-Shirt  22   650.80
>   CD       32   459.20

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SalesAnalysis {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of goods");
    int number=1;
    int goods=input.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=goods;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter information for item"+ number);
        number++;
        System.out.println("Name:");
        String name=input.next();
        String array[]=new String[]{name};
        System.out.println("Quantity:");
        int quantity=input.nextInt();
        int ar[]=new int[]{quantity};
        System.out.println("Amount (in USD):");
        double amount=input.nextDouble();
        double a[]=new double[]{amount};
        getQuantity(array,ar,a);
        getAmount(array,ar,a);
    }
    public static void getQuantity(String array[],int ar[],double a[]){
        System.out.println("Sort by Quantity:");
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        System.out.print("Item"+"      " +"Qty"+ "Amount" );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you don't know java well.

Create a class for Item. Keep name, quantity and amount as fields in it.
implement comparable interface while creating this class. Implete compareTo method to compare based on quantity.

While taking inputs from user, keep creating a object for a every single item with required details, keep adding these items in a arraylist.

Sort that arraylist (it will sort on quantity as you have implemented compareTo method).

Iterate over list, and print details.

I know you don't many of the things I mentioned here, but you will end up learning quite a few things about OOP and Java, this way.

Comment: This is the right kind of idea.  But since Anika needs two different sorts (by quantity and by price), it would make more sense to use Comparators, rather than implementing a natural order for the `Item` class.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: New and improved answer.**
So to start out doing this you are going to want to make an Item class, that can store information such as the item's name, the items quantity, and the items price. Here is how I have done this:

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName () {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setQuantity (int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public int getQuantity () {
        return this.quantity;
    }
    public void setPrice (double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public double getPrice () {
        return this.price;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have made all of the stored variables private so I am using getters and setters.
From here you are going to want to make a way for users to input items. I have not set up an UI for this but instead I have made it where the program reads the file in its folder named `input.txt`. I did this like so:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ItemManager {

    public Item[] items;
    public Item[] sortedByQuantity;
    public Item[] sortedByPrice;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filepath = "input.txt";
        if(args.length >= 1) {
            if(args[0] != null) {
                filepath = args[0];
            }
        }
        ItemManager runProgram = new ItemManager();
        runProgram.AssignValues(filepath);
        runProgram.Display();
    }
```

From here the system then analyzes the contents of `input.txt` using a scanner such as you have done. The input file should be formatted like this:
ItemName(no spaces) Quantity Price
new line for new item

```
public void AssignValues(String filepath) {
        try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
                if(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
            }
            String content = sb.toString();
            tokenizeTerms(content);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("InputDocument File IOException");
        }
    }
```

This method uses string builder to compile a single string out of the input text. From here it calls tokenizeTerms on the content. This method splits the string into a String[], using a space as a delimiter, hence not being able to use spaces in the item names.

```
public void tokenizeTerms(String content) {
        String[] tokenizedTerms = content.split(" ");
        Item[] itemArray = new Item[tokenizedTerms.length/3];
        int currToken = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
            itemArray[i] = new Item();
            try {
                itemArray[i].setName(tokenizedTerms[currToken]);
                currToken++;
                int foo = Integer.parseInt(tokenizedTerms[currToken]);
                itemArray[i].setQuantity(foo);
                currToken++;
                double moo = Double.parseDouble(tokenizedTerms[currToken]);
                itemArray[i].setPrice(moo);
                currToken++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error parsing data.");
            } 
        }
        this.sortedByPrice = itemArray;
        this.sortedByQuantity = itemArray;
        this.items = itemArray;
    }
```

In this method it also creates a temporary array of Items. Which are then iterated though using a for-loop and the items are assigned there corresponding tokenized values from the input text. Now all we have to do is sort the arrays and print them in the console. As you can see above in the main method, we call `Display()`.

```
public void Display() {
        Arrays.sort(sortedByQuantity, (Item i1, Item i2) -> Double.compare(i1.getQuantity(), i2.getQuantity()));
        Arrays.sort(sortedByPrice, (Item i1, Item i2) -> Double.compare(i1.getPrice(), i2.getPrice()));
        System.out.println("Sorted by quantity:");
        for(Item currItem : sortedByQuantity) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + currItem.getName() + " Quantity: " + currItem.getQuantity() + " Price: " + currItem.getPrice());
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted by price:");
        for(Item currItem : sortedByPrice) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + currItem.getName() + " Quantity: " + currItem.getQuantity() + " Price: " + currItem.getPrice());
        }
    }
```

The code starts out by first using lambda expressions to sort the arrays based off a custom compare method. From here we just iterate through each array and print each value.
That is the basic setup for what you are looking for, you can now modify these methods to your liking and apply them in whatever way seems fit. You also could also modify it to allow users to directly input the values in the software, or modify it to allow item names to have spaces. Best of luck.

Comment: There, I have broken the script into working methods that will allow him to take the ideas behind them and apply them to his own script and have went into depth as to how they work. Also the reason my first version was so bad was because I made it in notepad and I am best at C# not java.